# iOS 7 MKMapView Missing Voice Turn-by-Turn Directions

Tags: objective-c, apple-maps

I am not getting voice directions when invoking apple map directions.

Here is my code.

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoord = [self.userLocation coordinate];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D opponentCoord = [self.opponentLocation coordinate];
    MKPlacemark *fromPlace = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:userCoord addressDictionary:nil];
    MKPlacemark *destinationPlace = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:opponentCoord addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *fromItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:fromPlace];
    fromItem.name = @"Current Location";
    MKMapItem *destinationItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destinationPlace];
    destinationItem.name = self.game[@"opponent"];
    NSArray *items = @[fromItem, destinationItem];
    NSDictionary *options = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey:@(MKMapTypeStandard), MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey:@YES};
    [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:items launchOptions:options];
```

Navigation Voice Volume on my iPhone 5S is set to Normal and I have restarted my phone. Voice turn-by-by directions works fine all other times, just not from my app.